# WebClient Post to MVC Controller From NServiceBus/Queue Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nservicebus

So I queue up a message in my NServiceBus service localhost. My NServiceBus service gets the message does some work and then tries to call an ASP.NET MVC Controller with the following signature:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public void MyMethod(long accountId, long channelId, long messageId)
```

I am using `System.Net.WebClient` to attempt an `HttpPost` with this code:

```
var url= "http://localhost:53777/MyMethod";
var _accIdStr = Convert.ToString(_accountIdLong);
var _chanIdStr = Convert.ToString(_channelIdLong);
var _messIdStr = Convert.ToString(_messageIdLong);

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
     var values = new NameValueCollection
     {
          { "accountId", _accIdStr },
          { "channelId", _chanIdStr },
          { "messageId", _messIdStr }
     };
     var responsebytes = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", values);
     var responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
}
```

I am just getting the error:

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

I have a breakpoint set in `MyMethod` and it is not even getting hit, there is no entry into `MyMethod`. Its making me think the signature of `MyMethod` is not getting routed to.

Or maybe this is because I am localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not likely.  500 typically means that your MVC application threw an exception.

If the breakpoint doesn't get hit, then the model binder isn't binding the post data to the fields property.

If it does get hit, identify the line of code that's crashing and resolve the issue.

Also, looks like you're trying to access the controller without including the controller name.  Default MVC route is: BASEURL/CONTROLLERNAME/ACTION,  where ACTION is MyMethod.  So yours should be http:// localhost:53777/CONTROLLERNAME/MyMethod

Comment: Yes I have a break point set, it is not even hitting "MyMethod"

Comment: Just remembered also that this should be in the format of localhost/CONTROLLERNAME/MyMethod

Comment: That was it! Thanks alot. I am so out of steam I am was sitting here refreshing this question, waiting for an answer lol ;)

Comment: To be clear the answer is that I did not have the ControllerName included in my URL

Comment: Haha, we've all been there at some point. Just glad I could help.